# mod_rewrite remove .htaccess still working

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

First page is use mod_rewrite for www.test/about/somthing
It's working but not get $id

but my Second page i use mod_rewrite for www.test/custom/somthing
It's working and get $id

Then i decide to delete .htaccess from server and test again

www.test/custome/somthing <<< not working and page return not found

www.test/about/somthing <<< It's still working but not get $id

Here is my code

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} ^(TRACE|TRACK)
RewriteRule .* - [F]

# RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)$ [NC]
# RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [R=301,L]

# website rewrite down here
# -------------------------------------------------------------------

RewriteRule ^about/(.*)$ about.php?id=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^custom/(.*)$ custom.php?id=$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
```

Help me i thing ghost all around me now :(

Comment: RewriteRule ^(about)/(.*)$ about.php?id=$2 [L]

Answer (score 1):

Your rule aren't correct.

Try this code:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} ^(TRACE|TRACK)
RewriteRule .* - [F]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [R=301,L]

# website rewrite down here
# -------------------------------------------------------------------

RewriteRule ^about/(.*)$ about.php?id=$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^custom/(.*)$ custom.php?id=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Your code has 2 overlapping rules for identical patterns `/about/`

Comment: I try to fix like your code but it's still not working

Comment: Are you getting 404 for `www.test/custom/something`?

Comment: I getting 404 for www.test/custom/something when i delete file .htaccess

Comment: But why are you deleting this .htaccess? I am asking asking with this .htaccess in place what happens when you open `www.test/custom/something`?